# MongoDB Aggregation - Change a value of field based on other field value in deeply nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have a number of documents in my collection. Each object is a user object which contains thoughts and thoughts have replies. What I want is when a reply has anonymous true, its username value should say anonymous instead of the username value.

Document

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6276eb2195b181d38eee0b43"
    },
    "username": "abvd",
    "password": "efgh",
    "thoughts": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "62778ff975e2c8725b9276f5"
        },
        "text": "last  thought",
        "anonymous": true,
        "replies": [
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "62778fff75e2c8725b9276f5"
            },
            "text": "new reply",
            "anonymous": true,
            "username": "cdf"
          },
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "62778fff75e2c8725b9276f5"
            },
            "text": "new reply",
            "anonymous": false,
            "username": "cdf"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output Required. If you see the value in username says anonymous even though the existing document has "cdf" as the value

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6276eb2195b181d38eee0b43"
    },
    "username": "abvd",
    "password": "efgh",
    "thoughts": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "62778ff975e2c8725b9276f5"
        },
        "text": "last  thought",
        "anonymous": true,
        "replies": [
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "62778fff75e2c8725b9276f5"
            },
            "text": "new reply",
            "anonymous": true,
            "username": "anonymous"
          },
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "62778fff75e2c8725b9276f5"
            },
            "text": "new reply",
            "anonymous": false,
            "username": "cdf"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Let me know if you know how to help.
Here's a MongoDB Playground URL containing the existing document:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/WoP-3z-DMuf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit complex query.

1. `$set` - Update the `thoughts` field.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate each `thought` document and return new document from *1.1.1*.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge objects for `thoughts` document and `replies` array from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. `$map` - Iterate the `reply` document, return the new document by merging `reply` document and `username` field with updating its value based on the `anonymous` field via `$cond`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      thoughts: {
        $map: {
          input: "$thoughts",
          as: "thought",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$thought",
              {
                replies: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$thought.replies",
                    as: "reply",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$reply",
                        {
                          username: {
                            "$cond": {
                              "if": "$$reply.anonymous",
                              "then": "anonymous",
                              "else": "$$reply.username"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZuJD8Gjktei)